# Set password for service user on windows using ansible

Tags: windows, automation, ansible

I was trying to use ansible module on windows machine to set user and password on existing service.

link to module :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_module.html

- name: Set the log on user to a local account

  ansible.windows.win_service:

  name: service name

  state: restarted

  username: .\my_user

  password: SomePassword#1111

My custom user is added to admin group.
After this task is done, user is set to service, but password is wrong.
If I try to start the service I have logon failure, if I paste manually same password it works. So why the same password is not working through Ansible?

Best regards,
Raven.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was a .bat script that needed to run as a logon user. Here is what I did to make it work. I used NSSM to create the service the the win_service module to update the password.

```
  - name: Grant user right
    win_user_right:
      name: SeServiceLogonRight
      users:
        - "{{ my_user }}"
      action: add

  - name: create service with nssm
    win_nssm:
      name: my-service
      application: "test.bat"
      stderr_file: "error.log"

  - name: Set user
    win_service:
      name: my-service
      username: "{{ my_user }}"
      password: "{{ my_pass  }}"
      update_password: always
      state: started
```